# Flux consumer doesnt stop to consume data

Tags: java, spring-webflux, flux

I have this implementation

```
@Override
public Flux<byte[]> translateData(final String datasetId) {
    return keyVaultRepository.findByDatasetId(datasetId)
            .map(keyVault -> {
                try {
                    return translatorService.createTranslator(keyVault.getKey()); // throws CryptoException in the test
                } catch (CryptoException e) {
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(new ApiException("Unable to provide translated file"));
                }
            })
            .flatMapMany(translator -> storageService.getEntry(datasetId).map(translator::update));
}
```

and this failing test

```
@Test
void getTranslatedDataWithError() throws StorageException, CryptoException {
    final List<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<>();

    // exec + validate
    getWebTestClient()
            .get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/{datasetId}").build(datasetId))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is5xxServerError()
            .returnResult(byte[].class)
            .getResponseBody()
            .onErrorStop()
            .subscribe(bytes::add);
    
    assertThat(bytes).isEmpty();
}
```

the part `.is5xxServerError()` is succeeding but the list is **not** empty.

The Microservice which is calling the endpoint of `translateData`  should not consume any data from upstream but apparently this is the case.

I've found a workaround by throwing a `RuntimeException`  in the catch block (I could also make the `CryptoException`  unchecked but thats not the matter of my question) and then handle the case in my ControllerAdvice/GlobalExceptionhandler and just return a `ResponseEntity`  with an `ErrorDto` .

The core of my question is, how can I do this natively with Flux. So that the consumer of the endpoint notices there is an error and `.subscribe(bytes::add);`  wont be even executed.

I have tried it already with `.doOnError` , `.onErrorResume`  etc. but it always ends with a non empty list :(

By this I am afraid that the bytes will later delivered to the client (which should not of course he should get an error response)